# Pie Chart With Pattern fill : Jqplot Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

I am using jqplot for making pie chart.. In this i want to create a pie chart like following image..[image: Pie chart with Pattern filling]

It is Possible to do that?? using jqplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for jqPlot, but used highcharts instead. You can check the  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ErU8H/)

code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Pattern fill plugin demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            from: 100,
            to: 200,
            color: {
                pattern: 'https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/graphics/pattern3.png',
                width: 6,
                height: 6
            }
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        fillColor: {
            pattern: 'https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/graphics/pattern1.png',
            width: 6,
            height: 6
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: [148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6],
        color: {
            pattern: 'https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/graphics/pattern2.png',
            width: 6,
            height: 6,
            // VML only:
            color1: 'red',
            color2: 'yellow'
        }
    }]

});
```